# Storing an image in public/images using Laravel9 Vue3

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am currently using Laravel9 and Vue3 and I am trying to upload an image to a folder in public/images named cars_images and, after that, store the link of that image in a table called cars, in the image zone.. I am rather new to coding and I lack the knowledge to make all of this possible atm, any help would be apreciated.

Here is the component that I am trying to upload it to
(PS. I have more requests in there so the addcar submit is already there , I just need help with this specific problem.

```
<template>
 <form
  @submit.prevent="addcar"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
 >
   <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
        <input
        type="file"
        class="form-control form-control-lg"
       />
   </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
methods: {
        addcar() {
            axios
                .post("/api/addcar", this.form)

                .catch((error) => console.log(error.response.data));
        },
}
</script>
```

And the php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Car;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

    // add car
    public function addcar(Request $request)
    {
        $car = new Car([            
         'image' =>$request->image,
        ]);
        $car->save();

        return response()->json('Car successfully added');
    }
```

And the route in routes api

```
Route::post('/addcar', [CarController::class, 'addcar']);
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should add in order to help.

Comment: I don't see any image upload. how to upload a file is well documented, so take a look at the laravel docs. You should also upload the images to the public storage folder that can be linked to the public folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple image save function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required'
    ]);

    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

    $form_data = array(
        'image' => $new_name,
    );

    YOUR_MODEL::create($form_data);

    return redirect('YOUR_PAGE')->with('success', 'Image Added successfully.');
}
```